# Best way to persist NSDictionary indefinitely

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I've got an app that relies on a single moderately large (300kb) data pull onload, of data that changes significantly on regular intervals of about once every 2-3 months.  It is reasonably fast to load, but I'm trying to build in more robust support for offline usage and not having to reload it each time for no reason.  The data is JSON that is serialized directly to a deep, multilevel NSDictionary structure that is easy to use.  So, I'm happy keeping the NSDictionary format if I can.

**The Usage Scenarios/Ideas:**

- The dictionary persists automatically while the app is in background of course, so resuming it doesn't have to to reload it on viewWillAppear if it exists.
- More significantly when the app terminates, it needs to reload the data to memory without a new request each time.  It seems too large and inappropriate to store in UserDefaults.  Yet too complex to put in CoreData or SQLLite for just persistence attempts.
- I've thought about flat file store, but am not sure plist conversion is the best format, and am unfamiliar with a way to serialize/deserialize a massive NSDictionary to regular text.
- Finally, it ultimately needs to know to refresh itself if the data eventually becomes stale.  I've considered using NSURLConnection various cache options, but am not sure of the appropriate options for such a scenario.

Looking for suggested best-approaches for this scenario.

**EDIT The rough solution I went with, saving to file:**

Called in the AppDelegate on load/exit appropriately, with URL load as a fallback.

```
- (void) saveResultsToFile {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"schedule.plist"];
    BOOL writeSuccess = [_routeData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}

- (void) readResultsFromFile {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"schedule.plist"];
    _routeData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's too large for user defaults? Have you tried it?

Comment: A plist is just fine. Don't over-engineer it.

Comment: And user defaults shouldn't be used for user data - that's not what it's for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you're on the right track.

1. `[dataDictionary writeToFile:<#(NSString *)#> atomically:<#(BOOL)#>];` **and** `dataDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:<#(NSString *)#>]` persistence is a good thing to do but of course you should use background threads if you're going to process that file right away.
2. Also, using the caching mechanism it's a great idea but please take a look at **SDURLCache** (https://github.com/steipete/SDURLCache) as `NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData` is currently unimplemented.

Answer (score 3):

For big amount of data that take a lot of memory (over few MB) I would recommend to go for CoreData.

It gives you best memory usage - doesn't load all objects into memory so you don't have any risky memory picks which can cause crash. Also it gives you most optimal sorting / filtering methods.

If you are doing something with that data (like filtering, sorting) and probably it will grow in future - don't keep everything in memory and use proper tools for unlimited data filtering / displaying. When you use NSFetchedResultController and all tools from XCode 5 it's really easy to work with and you get a lot of most complicated stuff for free ;)

If you don't want to work with CoreData or you don't use too much memory, you can consider just saving file into documents folder with NSCoding and keeping it in binary file.

Comment: I'd be curious to see iOS crashing because someone loaded 300kB of data into memory... Considering the technology and complexity behind CD, I'm pretty darn confident that the memory usage that you win by not loading the entire thing into memory is lost again because of using CoreData. As to the "easier to use" argument: that's... khm, an oxymoron at best, "CoreData" and "easy" in the same sentence... CD has quite a learning curve, and it is definitely not "easier" to use than a simple keypath query on an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Yeah I understood it is 300k entries more than 300kb file - author didn't write about size, but thanks for pointing that out - I updated answer to be more generic

Comment: 300kb is actually the approximate size of the NSUrlRequest's response.  I control the other end and have optimized it down to that, so I don't foresee it changing much in size.  Maybe 500kb worst case scenario one day.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` to save small amounts of data. It isn't quite as secure as other channels, but works great for storing `NSDictionary` objects. Easy to save, easy to retrieve.

Comment: 300k of user data doesn't belong in user defaults.

Comment: There are other channels, but still works. The file is restricted to just your app, so there isn't any danger of saving it there if you only access it when the app is running. 300k doesn't belong there is your opinion, but is still a viable option.

Comment: Many things are viable options - but not recommended. There is a difference between answering the question asked and answering the actual deeper question.

Comment: Sure, I see your answer right... oh right. You didn't answer. So answer the question with something that will work and be easy. Oh, and be sure to extoll on the virtues of not using NSUserDefaults.

Comment: I don't need to answer, I've upvoted the answers that are better. And "If you're so clever why don't you answer it?" doesn't really work with me.